# How to dispach a custom event inside httpservice result event

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

In my AIR application, I try to dispatch a custom event from a class to main window.
This class is use to call httpservice. My goal is to send a custom window when the httpservice result is send.

```
package fr.inter.DataProvider
{
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.EventDispatcher;

    import fr.inter.config.urlManager;
    import fr.kapit.introspection.components.DisplayListComponent;

    import mx.collections.XMLListCollection;
    import mx.rpc.events.FaultEvent;
    import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;
    import mx.rpc.http.HTTPService;

    [Event(name="evtPatSelect", type="flash.events.Event")]

    public class sPatient
    {

        private var _phppaIndex:String;
        private var _phppaNomU:String;
        private var _phppaPrenom:String;
        private var phpSearchPatNom:HTTPService;


        public function sPatient()
        {

        }


        public function sPhpSearchPat(p:Object):void
        {

            phpSearchPatNom = new HTTPService();
            phpSearchPatNom.method="POST";
            phpSearchPatNom.resultFormat = "e4x";
            phpSearchPatNom.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT,resultListePatient);
            phpSearchPatNom.addEventListener(FaultEvent.FAULT,serviceFault);
            var urlPhp:urlManager=new urlManager();
            phpSearchPatNom.url = urlPhp.urlService() + "20SearchNom.php";
            phpSearchPatNom.send(p);
        }


        private function resultListePatient( event:ResultEvent ):void
        {

            var xmlList:XMLList = XML(event.result).patientPHP;
            var xmlListColl = new XMLListCollection(xmlList);


            if(xmlListColl.length==1)
            {

                _phppaIndex = xmlListColl.getItemAt(0).paIndex;
                _phppaNomU = xmlListColl.getItemAt(0).paNomU;
                _phppaPrenom = xmlListColl.getItemAt(0).paPrenom;

                var evtPat:Event = new Event("evtPatSelect");

                var evdips:EventDispatcher = new EventDispatcher();
                evdips.dispatchEvent(evtPat);

            }
        }



        private function serviceFault( event:FaultEvent )
        {
            trace( event.fault.message );
        }

        public function get phppaIndex():String
        {
            return _phppaIndex;
        }

        public function set phppaIndex(value:String):void
        {
            _phppaIndex = value;
        }

        public function get phppaNomU():String
        {
            return _phppaNomU;
        }

        public function set phppaNomU(value:String):void
        {
            _phppaNomU = value;
        }

        public function get phppaPrenom():String
        {
            return _phppaPrenom;
        }

        public function set phppaPrenom(value:String):void
        {
            _phppaPrenom = value;
        }


    }
}
```

In main window I've added a eventlistener but this seems not works. 
Can you help me to solve that?

Thanks

Comment: If you want to use a separate event dispatcher and have other things be able to listen to your instance as if it were dispatching the events, you need to implement IEventDispatcher http://flexdiary.blogspot.com/2008/11/implementing-ieventdispatcher.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, extend the sPatient class as an EventDispatcher

```
public class sPatient extends EventDispatcher {
```

Then, create a class for your custom Event

```
public class MyCustomEvent extends Event {
        public static const CUSTOM_TITLE:String = "custom_title";
        public var eventData:Object;

        public function CustomEvent(type:String, bubbles:Boolean = false, cancelable:Boolean = false, data:Object = null) {
            super(type, bubbles, cancelable);
            if(data != null) eventData = data;
        }

        public override function clone():Event {
            return new CustomEvent(type, bubbles, cancelable);
        }

        public override function toString():String {
            return formatToString("CustomEvent", "type", "bubbles", "cancelable", "eventPhase");
        }
    }
```

Then in your sPatient class, go:

```
this.dispatchEvent(new MyCustomEvent(MyCustomEvent.CUSTOM_TITLE));
```

And listen for it like so

```
sPatientInstance.addEventListener(MyCustomEvent.CUSTOM_TITLE,functionHandler);
```

Comment: It's not necessary to write an Event Class simply to define the name of an event. If you feel the need to define constants, then create an enumeration Class that simply has static constants without the overhead of event instantiation. See the Flex *EventKind Classes for examples. If it weren't for the suggestion to write a custom Class unnecessarily, I would have upvoted your answer.

Comment: thanks for your answers. Amy can you explain with more details how to do without Event class. Thanks

Comment: @AmyBlankenship I was under the impression that he wanted to send custom objects along with the event, in which case he does need a custom event. On a side note, I ALWAYS create a custom event for things like this, it just feels right.

Comment: Flex60460: You already had the code to do that correct: dispatchEvent(new Event('yourEvent')).  But the object that was dispatching the event was not the same one that was being listened to.